# Exporting results from powershell into a CSV document not working

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script in Powershell that will pull all files in a directory from the past seven years (this is my first time using Powershell).

I am trying to Export my results from the script below into a TXT or CSV document.

```
get-childitem -Path P:\ -recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (getdate).Addyears(-7)}
```

What should I add to the end of this script to get this data written to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, your script is finding files **older than 7 years** not files from the last 7 years. You need to change your `-lt` to a `-gt`.

```
get-childitem -Path P:\ -recurse| where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).Addyears(-7)}
```

As you have written your script it finds the date/time that the file was last written to, for example 3/24/2015 2:45PM. Then it checks if that is less than right now minus 7 years (at the time of writing that is 12/5/2010 3:22PM). Looking at the years alone we can see that 2015 is not less than 2010, so that file would be excluded.

You can output to a text file using the `Out-File` or (my preference) `Set-Content` cmdlets.

```
get-childitem -Path P:\ -recurse| where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).Addyears(-7)} | Set-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt
```

Alternatively if you want to capture the data as well, or display it on screen, you can use the `Tee-Object` cmdlet.

```
get-childitem -Path P:\ -recurse| where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).Addyears(-7)} | Tee-Object -FilePath C:\Path\To\File.txt
```

If you would like a CSV file you use the `Export-Csv` cmdlet. When using this cmdlet it is very common to use the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter (shortened to `-NoType` in my example) to avoid getting a first line that specifies the object types that it output.

```
get-childitem -Path P:\ -recurse| where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).Addyears(-7)} | Export-Csv C:\Path\To\File.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

get-childitem -path p:\ -recurse | where-object{$_.lastwritetime -lt((get-date).adddyears(-7))} | export-csv c:\temp\test.csv